# mysql query doesnt give me the same result when i create view

Tags: mysql

```
select packages.id AS id,
packages.co_id AS co_id,
(select companies.name from companies where (packages.co_id = companies.id)) AS co_name,
(select companies.tel from companies where (packages.co_id = companies.id)) AS tel,
packages.datetime AS datetime,
(select tracking.datetime from tracking where (packages.id = tracking.pid and action='tookit')) AS tooktime,
(select tracking.datetime from tracking where (packages.id = tracking.pid and action='putit')) AS puttime,
packages.status AS status from packages
```

this query works good as it should when i run it but when i made it as a view doesnt show the same result i get nulls in the fields of "tracking" table

i recreated the query still have the issue

```
SELECT t1.id , t1.co_id , t2.name, t2.tel, t1.datetime , t3.datetime as tookit, t4.datetime as putit
FROM packages as t1

INNER JOIN companies as t2
ON t1.co_id=t2.id

left JOIN tracking as t3
ON t1.id = t3.pid and t3.action ='tookit'

left JOIN tracking as t4
ON t1.id = t4.pid and t4.action ='putit'
```

i appreciate any help

Comment: Is there any chance that your underlying data has changed?

Comment: no, i make refresh in both the query and the view in the same time no same result

Comment: Does your view look almost the same as the query?  Or is there different logic there?

Comment: Why don't you include the definition of the view?

Comment: the top shows result without creating the view,
the results in the bottom after i created the view
[link](https://s28.postimg.org/49xax48bx/123.png)

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten your query check if it helps.

```
    SELECT 
        packages.id AS id,
        packages.co_id AS co_id,
        companies.name AS co_name,
        companies.tel AS tel,
        packages.datetime AS DATETIME,
        t1.datetime AS tooktime,
        t2.datetime AS puttime,
        packages.status AS STATUS 
    FROM
      packages 
      LEFT JOIN companies 
        ON packages.co_id = companies.id 
      LEFT JOIN tracking t1 
        ON packages.id = t1.pid 
        AND t1.ACTION = 'tookit' 
      LEFT JOIN tracking t2 
        ON packages.id = t2.pid 
        AND t2.ACTION = 'putit'
```

Comment: Unknown column 't1.tracking.datetime' in 'field list'

Comment: Edited my answer check now.

Comment: it works but sorry to tell you that it gave me the same result

Comment: it not changing, tracking table has related data, its really weird